# How to refer to matched groups in jq gsub?

Tags: regular-expression, jq, pattern-matching, pcre

Using `jq`, I want to search for a pattern via regex, and wrap the **matched** string with something like `<div>` tags

```bsh
$ echo "\"This is a valid json file"\" | jq '. | gsub("valid";"how_to_refer_to_matches";"i") -
```

How to refer to the matched results in the second argument of `gsub`?
What if there are more than 1 matches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ jq -n '"some string" | gsub("(?<a>[[:lower:]]+)"; "<div>\(.a)</div>")'
"<div>some</div> <div>string</div>"
```

or

```
$ jq -n '"some string" | gsub("(?<a>[[:lower:]]+)"; "<div>" + .a + "</div>")'
"<div>some</div> <div>string</div>"
```

This replaces each run of lowercase letters with the same letters, flanked by `<div>` and `</div>`.  The capture is done with `(?<a>RE)` where `a` is a key name that you can refer to in the replacement using `.a` (it does not need to be a single letter), and where `RE` is some expression.  You may capture multiple groups with different key names at the same time.

`gsub()` works like e.g. `gsub()` in `awk` and like `s///g` in Perl, `sed`, and `ed`, so it will perform the substitution once for each non-overlapping match of the expression.  This is illustrated in my example above where there are two matches of the pattern in the string.

---

Just to use a more similar example as you:

```
$ jq -n '"this is a valid JSON string" | gsub("(?<match>valid)"; "<div>" + .match + "</div>")'
"this is a <div>valid</div> JSON string"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me where in the docs this notation : (?<a>RE) is mentioned? https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Look at the documentation for `gsub`. It refers to the documentation of `sub` (which only handles the _first_ match on a line), which in turn mentions the `capture` function.  What you are looking for is in the documentation of `sub` and `capture`.

Comment: Thanks https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example82

Comment: What would be the difference between `gsub` and `sub(;;"g")` (with global switch) ? Should I open another question?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Functionally, it would be no difference at all.  It would just be slightly more obfuscated code which would be harder to understand.

Comment: One more thing: `\(.a)` is the whole match. How can I get the groups? Due to the docs, it should be key `captures` of the match. So `\(.a.captures[].string)`. But this doesn't work. For example `gsub("(?<a>(123.*321))";...)` How can I get only `.*` excluding 123 and 321 around it?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator No, `.a` is only the group that you matched with `(?<a>RE)`. If the expression RE covers the whole match, then `.a` is the whole match.  For another example, try `(?<a>.).(?<b>.)` and replace with e.g. `\(.b)\(.a)`.  This would transform `test string` into `ststitng`, just like in `echo 'test string' | sed 's/\(.\).\(.\)/\2\1/g'`.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Using your example from your last comment (which I didn't see at first, sorry), you would write the expression as `123(?<a>.*)321`.